# Error:Dimension out of range. Multi-class text classification with nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

Tags: python, pytorch, text-classification, multiclass-classification

I' a newbie in text classification and I'm trying to create a multiclass text classification. First this code worked like a charm for a binary classification but I'm trying to convert it into multiclass clasification. I switched loss function from nn.BCELoss() to nn.CrossEntropyLoss() and I removed the softmax because CrossEntropyLoss has that included but now I get an error IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)

Please let me know if I need to add anything else

```
n_epochs = 3
best_valid_loss = float('inf')
t_loss=[]
v_loss=[]

for epoch in range(n_epochs):
     
    train_loss, train_acc = train(model, train_iterator,optimizer, criterion)
    
    valid_loss, valid_acc = evaluate(model, valid_iterator, criterion)
    
    if valid_loss < best_valid_loss:
        best_valid_loss = valid_loss
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'saved_weights.pt')
    
    t_loss.append(train_loss)
    v_loss.append(valid_loss)
    
    print(f'\tTrain Loss: {train_loss:.3f} | Train Acc: {train_acc*100:.2f}%')
    print(f'\t Val. Loss: {valid_loss:.3f} |  Val. Acc: {valid_acc*100:.2f}%') 

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-130-88e45751bc44> in <module>()
      6 for epoch in range(n_epochs):
      7 
----> 8     train_loss, train_acc = train(model, train_iterator,optimizer, criterion)
      9 
     10     valid_loss, valid_acc = evaluate(model, valid_iterator, criterion)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in cross_entropy(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction)
   2822     if size_average is not None or reduce is not None:
   2823         reduction = _Reduction.legacy_get_string(size_average, reduce)
-> 2824     return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index)
   2825 
   2826 

IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)
```

Here is the full code to recreate:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import re
import spacy
import string
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch
import torchtext
from torchtext.legacy import data
from torchtext.legacy import datasets
#from torchtext import data
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    
seed=50
torch.manual_seed(seed)
torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
```

Data loader:

```
class DataFrameDataset(data.Dataset):

    def __init__(self, df, fields, is_test=False, **kwargs):
        examples = []
        for i, row in df.iterrows():
            label = row.target if not is_test else None
            text = row.text
            examples.append(data.Example.fromlist([text, label], fields))

        super().__init__(examples, fields, **kwargs)

    @staticmethod
    def sort_key(ex):
        return len(ex.text)

    @classmethod
    def splits(cls, fields, train_df, val_df=None, test_df=None, **kwargs):
        train_data, val_data, test_data = (None, None, None)
        data_field = fields

        if train_df is not None:
            train_data = cls(train_df.copy(), data_field, **kwargs)
        if val_df is not None:
            val_data = cls(val_df.copy(), data_field, **kwargs)
        if test_df is not None:
            test_data = cls(test_df.copy(), data_field, True, **kwargs)

        return tuple(d for d in (train_data, val_data, test_data) if d is not None)
```

Data preparation

```
def data_preparation(train, valid, batch_size):

  text=data.Field(tokenize='spacy', batch_first=True, include_lengths=True) #spacy je tokenizer
  label=data.LabelField(dtype=torch.float, batch_first=True)

  fields = [('text',text),('label', label)]
  train_ds, valid_ds=DataFrameDataset.splits(fields, train_df=train, val_df=valid)

  text.build_vocab(train_ds, min_freq=3, vectors="glove.6B.200d")
  label.build_vocab(train_ds)
  
  print("Size of TEXT vocabulary:",len(text.vocab))
  print("Size of LABEL vocabulary:",len(label.vocab))

  train_iterator, valid_iterator=data.BucketIterator.splits((train_ds,valid_ds),
                                                          batch_size=batch_size, sort_key= lambda x:len(x.text),
                                                          sort_within_batch=True,
                                                          device=device)
  
  vocab_size=len(text.vocab)
  
  return text, vocab_size, train_iterator, valid_iterator
```

&

```
text, vocab_size, train_iterator, valid_iterator=data_preparation(train_d, valid_d,batch_size=128)
```

Defining the classifier

```
class classifier(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, hidden_dim, output_dim, n_layers, 
                 bidirectional, dropout):    
        super().__init__()          
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(embedding_dim,  
                           hidden_dim,  
                           num_layers= n_layers, 
                           dropout=dropout, 
                           batch_first=True) 
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_dim*2 , output_dim) 
        #self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=1) 
        
  def forward(self, text, text_lengths):
        
        embedded = self.embedding(text)
        packed_embedded = nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(embedded, text_lengths.cpu(),batch_first=True)    
        packed_output, (hidden, cell) = self.lstm(packed_embedded)
        hidden = torch.cat((hidden[-2,:,:], hidden[-1,:,:]), dim = 1)
        #dense_outputs=self.fc(hidden)
        #outputs=self.softmax(dense_outputs)
                    
        outputs=self.fc(hidden)

        return outputs
```

Parameters & defining model, loss function, optimizer...

```
size_of_vocab = vocab_size
embedding_dim = 50
num_hidden_nodes = 20
num_output_nodes = 1
num_layers = 3
bidirectional = True
dropout = 0.2

model = classifier(size_of_vocab, embedding_dim, num_hidden_nodes,num_output_nodes, num_layers, 
                   bidirectional, dropout = dropout)

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.002)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss() 

model = model.to(device)
criterion = criterion.to(device)

def binary_accuracy(preds, y):
    rounded_preds = torch.round(preds)
    
    correct = (rounded_preds == y).float() 
    acc = correct.sum() / len(correct)
    return acc
```

Model training and evaluating

```
def train(model, iterator,optimizer, criterion):
    
    epoch_loss = 0
    epoch_acc = 0
    
    model.train()  
    
    for batch in iterator:
      optimizer.zero_grad()   
      
      text, text_lengths = batch.text   
      predictions = model(text, text_lengths).squeeze()  
        
      loss = criterion(predictions, batch.label)        
      acc = binary_accuracy(predictions, batch.label)   
      
      loss.backward()
      optimizer.step()      
        
      epoch_loss += loss.item()  
      epoch_acc += acc.item()    
        
    return epoch_loss / len(iterator), epoch_acc / len(iterator)
```

&

```
def evaluate(model, iterator, criterion):
  
    epoch_loss = 0
    epoch_acc = 0

    model.eval()
    
    with torch.no_grad():
    
        for batch in iterator:
        
            text, text_lengths = batch.text
            
            predictions = model(text, text_lengths).squeeze()
            
            loss = criterion(predictions, batch.label)
            acc = binary_accuracy(predictions, batch.label)
            
            epoch_loss += loss.item()
            epoch_acc += acc.item()
        
    return epoch_loss / len(iterator), epoch_acc / len(iterator)
```

&

```
n_epochs = 3
best_valid_loss = float('inf')
t_loss=[]
v_loss=[]

for epoch in range(n_epochs):
     
    train_loss, train_acc = train(model, train_iterator,optimizer, criterion)
    
    valid_loss, valid_acc = evaluate(model, valid_iterator, criterion)
    
    if valid_loss < best_valid_loss:
        best_valid_loss = valid_loss
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'saved_weights.pt')
    
    t_loss.append(train_loss)
    v_loss.append(valid_loss)
    
    print(f'\tTrain Loss: {train_loss:.3f} | Train Acc: {train_acc*100:.2f}%')
    print(f'\t Val. Loss: {valid_loss:.3f} |  Val. Acc: {valid_acc*100:.2f}%')
```

Comment: Could you provide the shapes for `predictions` as well as `batch.label`?

Comment: @Ivan Hi Ivan. Thanks for the reply. What is the easiest way of getting the shape of predictions and batch.label? Thanks for the help

Comment: `predictions.shape` and `batch.label.shape`...